# How to read the latest Chkdsk event viewer log in PowerShell (on Windows 10)?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, chkdsk, event-log

As I find it rather cumbersome to run Event Viewer and filter out the latest Chkdsk log, may I poke a question:

How to read the latest Chkdsk event viewer log in PowerShell (on Windows 10)?

My humble requirements for the solution:

- It has to be done **in PowerShell** (not ISE, normal PowerShell terminal).
- It has to be done **without Administrator privileges** (to save some mouse clicks).

Important notes:

- I mean the Chkdsk scheduled at boot for the system drive, usually `C:`.
- Apart from the log, it should output the date and time, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find a solution, which does not *look pretty*, but you can always create an alias function for it:

```powershell
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname="Application"; id="1001"} | ?{$_.providername –match "wininit"} | Format-List TimeCreated, Message
```